# readdir and getdents interfaces -- number of bytes read?

Tags: c, unix, posix

I'm working on Cygwin, which does not implement [getdents](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getdents), nor [getdirentries](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/OpenBSD/man2/getdirentries.2.html).

The code I'm working on relies on knowing the number of bytes read, which is the return of these calls. All I seem to have is [readdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir_r.html).

Man pages are lacking in Cygwin. Any ideas, or existing documentation, on how to make these interfaces compatible, or how to get the number of bytes read from readdir?

Cygwin's `struct dirent`, in case it's relevant:

```
struct dirent
{
  uint32_t __d_version;                 /* Used internally */
  ino_t d_ino;
  unsigned char d_type;
  unsigned char __d_unused1[3];
  __uint32_t __d_internal1;
  char d_name[NAME_MAX + 1];
};
```

**EDIT**

The [code](http://git.suckless.org/9base/tree/lib9/dirread.c) that uses `getdents` is in function `readdir` (see the link for full file):

```
static int
mygetdents(int fd, struct dirent *buf, int n) {
  return syscall (getdents, fd, (void*) buf, n);
}

long
dirread(int fd, Dir **dp)
{
    char *buf;
    struct stat st;
    int n;

    *dp = 0;

    if(fstat(fd, &st) < 0)
        return -1;

    if(st.st_blksize < 8192)
        st.st_blksize = 8192;

    buf = malloc(st.st_blksize);
    if(buf == nil)
        return -1;

    n = mygetdents(fd, (void*)buf, st.st_blksize);
    if(n < 0){
        free(buf);
        return -1;
    }
    n = dirpackage(fd, buf, n, dp);
    free(buf);
    return n;
}

static int
dirpackage(int fd, char *buf, int n, Dir **dp)
{
    int oldwd;
    char *p, *str, *estr;
    int i, nstr, m;
    struct dirent *de;
    struct stat st, lst;
    Dir *d;

    n = countde(buf, n);
    if(n <= 0)
        return n;

    if((oldwd = open(".", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        return -1;
    if(fchdir(fd) < 0)
        return -1;

    p = buf;
    nstr = 0;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        de = (struct dirent*)p;
        memset(&lst, 0, sizeof lst);
        if(de->d_name[0] == 0)
            /* nothing */ {}
        else if(lstat(de->d_name, &lst) < 0)
            de->d_name[0] = 0;
        else{
            st = lst;
            if(S_ISLNK(lst.st_mode))
                stat(de->d_name, &st);
            nstr += _p9dir(&lst, &st, de->d_name, nil, nil, nil);
        }
        p += de->d_reclen;
    }

    d = malloc(sizeof(Dir)*n+nstr);
    if(d == nil){
        fchdir(oldwd);
        close(oldwd);
        return -1;
    }
    str = (char*)&d[n];
    estr = str+nstr;

    p = buf;
    m = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        de = (struct dirent*)p;
        if(de->d_name[0] != 0 && lstat(de->d_name, &lst) >= 0){
            st = lst;
            if((lst.st_mode&S_IFMT) == S_IFLNK)
                stat(de->d_name, &st);
            _p9dir(&lst, &st, de->d_name, &d[m++], &str, estr);
        }
        p += de->d_reclen;
    }

    fchdir(oldwd);
    close(oldwd);
    *dp = d;
    return m;
}

static int
countde(char *p, int n)
{
    char *e;
    int m;
    struct dirent *de;

    e = p+n;
    m = 0;
    while(p < e){
        de = (struct dirent*)p;
        if(de->d_reclen <= 4+2+2+1 || p+de->d_reclen > e)
            break;
        if(de->d_name[0]=='.' && de->d_name[1]==0)
            de->d_name[0] = 0;
        else if(de->d_name[0]=='.' && de->d_name[1]=='.' && de->d_name[2]==0)
            de->d_name[0] = 0;
        m++;
        p += de->d_reclen;
    }
    return m;
}
```

I haven't made sense of `dirpackage` yet, but I *think* I may get around that detail if I could get the return of `getdents` in another way.

Comment: Why do you need to know number of bytes read? `readdir()` should return internally allocated buffer unless you want to use reenterable `readdir_r()`. `getdents()` are the low-level interface for `readdir()` (usually it is a system call) -- unlike `readdir()` which returns single entry, `getdents()` returns all of them.

Comment: Since the `getdents` page says "This is not the function you are interested in", why are you using it?  Your code is close to buggy for doing so.  There isn't a glibc binding for it; that's another indication you're doing it wrong.  What do you think the advantage of using the raw system call is?

Comment: It's not my code, I'm just porting it.
@myaut So, can I use the size of the allocated buffer instead?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why does the fact that there isn't a glibc binding for `getdents()` releavant? Isn't it enough that it isn't POSIX?

Comment: “Number of bytes read” when reading a directory is not meaningful, it's an implementation detail. What is your program using it for? If the answer is “nothing”, then use 42, it's as good as any. If the answer is “[not nothing]”, then tell us what!

Comment: @Gilles See edit. I thought it might be less trouble if there existed a well-known method for getting an equivalent of the return value of `getdents` using only what's available in POSIX, hence my original question without code.

Comment: You've posted "the code that uses getdents", but it doesn't use the value returned by `getdents` other than to check if it is <0 (i.e. an error). What's the point of your question?

Comment: @davmac It's used later, isn't it? `n = dirpackage(fd, buf, n, dp);`

Comment: @ArthurChamz ok, my bad. But what is it used for in that method (`dirpackage`)? Is it possible that `n` is just a multiple of `struct dirent`'s size, i.e. the number of entries read multiplied by `sizeof(struct dirent)`?

Comment: @davmac I still don't know, that's why my question is phrased as it is, regarding the interfaces of `getdents` and `readdir`, rather than the actual code. I'm new with this kind of code and syscalls, so I thought about an alternative to the interface first. If there isn't, then there isn't really any point to this question and might as well start thinking in something else.

Comment: @ArthurChamz can you not post the code for the `dirpackage` function? Seems like doing so will potentially get you much more useful answers. My suspicion (as mentioned above) is that `getdents` returns a multiple of `struct dirent`, indicating how many entries it read. The equivalent when using `readdir` would be `1 * sizeof(struct dirent)`.

Comment: @davmac It is a bit long, so I didn't post it in the question, but it's in the [link I posted](http://git.suckless.org/9base/tree/lib9/dirread.c) (I'll make it a bit more obvious in an edit).

Comment: @davmac OK, I've posted it (I've been previously told here in SO not to post code this long, sorry for dragging the question too far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you posted to the `dirpackage` method:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    de = (struct dirent*)p;
    memset(&lst, 0, sizeof lst);
    if(de->d_name[0] == 0)
        /* nothing */ {}
    else if(lstat(de->d_name, &lst) < 0)
        de->d_name[0] = 0;
    else{
        st = lst;
        if(S_ISLNK(lst.st_mode))
            stat(de->d_name, &st);
        nstr += _p9dir(&lst, &st, de->d_name, nil, nil, nil);
    }
    p += de->d_reclen;
}
```

Here `n` comes from:

```
n = countde(buf, n);
```

... where the original value of `n` is supplied from the return of the `getdents` syscall. The name `countde` probably stands for "count directory entries".

As you can see from the loop, the return from `countde` represents the *number of entries returned by the `getdents` call*. Each iteration through the loop processes one directory entry (`de = (struct dirent*)p;`) and then finds the next one (`p += de->d_reclen;`).

That should be pretty straight-forward to translate to using `readdir`, since it only ever returns one entry.

Comment: Ah, I see... If I'm reading the docs right, then much of this code (like the whole `countde` function) isn't needed if I translate this to `readdir`, right?

Comment: @ArthurChamz that's how I see it, yes.